# Move Bitmap in canvas android java

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, move

My Question is how can I move a bitmap on a canvas?

Recently I'm making a game and There's a button.

When I'm clicking on this button I want to move the bitmap (Only X)
but when i'm doing this the bitmap is gone.

Here's the code :

"main_right" is the button that I'm clicking on.
I also tried to put "invalidate()" there but it also didn't work.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (x > width - main_right.getWidth()
                    && x < width - main_right.getWidth()
                            + main_right.getWidth()
                    && y > height
                            - (main_right.getHeight() + main_right.getHeight() / 2)
                    && y < height
                            - (main_right.getHeight() + main_right.getHeight() / 2)
                            + main_right.getHeight()) {

                x += 1;

                canvas_main.drawBitmap(image, (width / 2) + x2,
                        height - (image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2),
                        paint);

            } else {
                x = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the x position on your onTouchEvent and draw at your canvas inside the onDraw(Canvas), that is the surface you need to draw.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas_main.drawBitmap(image, (width / 2) + x,
                        height - (image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2),
                        paint);
```

The height might be the problem if your bitmap is > (device height/3)

```
height - (image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2)
```

In essence means height - 1.5*image height. Since the top left of the bitmap is placed at that coordinate, the image will disappear out of the screen.

It should be

```
height - (image.getHeight() - image.getHeight() / 2)
```

or

```
height - image.getHeight() / 2
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , I changed it and it still does not work.